# Enable the keyboard on the right side of the emulator

Tags: keyboard, 4.2-jelly-bean, emulators

I am currently using the latest Android SDK. Whenever I run a device, I can use the hardware buttons on the right side and the D-Pad.

But, there's no qwerty keyboard below it. Is there any way to make it show up?

[image: Old emulator (with QWERTY keyboard)]
Old emulator layout (with QWERTY keyboard)

[image: New emulator (without QWERTY keyboard)]
New emulator layout (without QWERTY keyboard)

Comment: Have you tried to double-tap the terminal? By default keyboard on Terminal Emulator on my Xplay does not show up too, double tapping the screen solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Find the emulator's configuration in your `HOME` directory.

```
~/.android/avd/<The_Device_Name>/config.ini
```

Here the `The_Device_Name` is the name of the android virtual device your created using the AVD Manager.

Open this configuration file(.ini) using Notepad editor and change the setting to have the below line which enable the keyboard

```
hw.keyboard=yes
```